# In how many ways can we allocate 5 people in 3 different rooms?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following task:

In how many ways can we allocate 5 people in 3 DIFFERENT rooms in such a way that every room will be non-empty and there will be max 2 people?

In my opinion the answer is:

${5 \choose 2}{3\choose 2}{1\choose 1}\cdot 3!$ and $3!$ is because we have three different rooms... Or maybe it should be ${3 \choose 1}$ instead?

Comment: You can quickly verify that with the given numbers you will necessarily have two rooms with two people each and one room with one person.  The answer of simply $3$ would be if the only distinguishing factor is which room it was who housed a single person, however it is generally the case that people are always considered distinguishable (*unless explicitly specified otherwise*) so there are certainly more than just $3$ outcomes.

Comment: As for your other answer attempt, no, that overcounts.  Better to set up the multiplication principle in the following way: Choose which room was the solo room, choose which person goes into the solo room.  For the left-most room intended for two people choose which two people they are.  The final room gets the final people.  Your first attempt overcounted by a factor of two.

Comment: Stretching your intuition around JMoravitz' comments, and assuming that people are distinguishable, I attack such a problem by *pretending* that the people have names (e.g. A, B, C, D, E).  Then, whatever formula I *conjure*, I ask myself how many times have I counted the **single** choice of (for example) [A] in room 1, [B, C] in room 2, [D, E]  in room 3?

Comment: Actually the fact that you're choosing 2, then 2, then 1 in a particular order already accounts for the distinctness of the rooms (no need for 3!). But, you need to add a 3C1 because you first need to choose the room that has one person.

Comment: Okay, so the answer is ${3\choose 1}\cdot{5\choose 1}\cdot{4\choose 2}$ I understand that If for example we would the situation when we want allocate different number in each room for example one person in one room, two people in second room and 3 people in third room then the solution would be quite different? Do we remember here that not only people but also rooms are distinguishable?

Comment: The answer is $\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$.  To see why, read JMoravitz's second comment.